How to build xmrig on windows with MSYS2 or VS 2022?
I am trying to build xmrig on Windows 11 using mingw compiler since 3 days, however I can't figure it out as I am constantly receiving errors. I'm following tutorial on official xmrig page.
What have I tried:
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc git make
git clone https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig.git
mkdir xmrig/build && cd xmrig/build
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DXMRIG_DEPS=xmrig-deps/gcc/x64
make -j$(nproc)

output:
C:/msys64/home/PC/xmrig/src/base/io/Signals.cpp:38:12: 
error: 'SIGPIPE' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'SIGFPE'?
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
       ^~~~~~~
       SIGFPE`

And:
git clone https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig.git
mkdir xmrig\build && cd xmrig\build
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 -DXMRIG_DEPS=c:\xmrig-deps\msvc2019\x64
cmake --build . --config Release

output:
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\lib64\libuv.so.1.0.0' [C:\Users\PC\xmrig\build\xmrig.vcxproj]

I tried resolving the second way by building libuv, but this gave me only DLLs or errors about lack of sys/socket.h even though I'm building on Windows.

Have you tried with -GNinja to use Ninja as build tool? It works better cross-platform and it's fast.
